# I want to create a Flow that will trigger an email alert

Tags: custom-list, email, alert, power-automate

I have a custom list that I need to create a Power Automate trigger to send an email alert similar the the "Alert me" option. [image: Alert me]

I want the alert to be sent to the assigned part whenever a new item is created or an existing item is modified. I have that part figured out but it is the alert that I am having trouble with. I can get an email to send a custom notification email but what I want it to send is below. Any ideas?

[image: email]

EDIT: Going to go about this a different way. Here is what I am thinking...

When a item is created or modified I receive an alert in my inbox. This is the OOTB alert, which is really nice because it provides great detail and identities changes of an item.

What I want to happen now is that alert be forwarded to the “assigned to” email address from the item. Like this...

Email received as SP alert > data pulled from the list / item (I imagine this will be done external of the actual email but via the list / item itself) > email forwarded to the “assigned to” email address

Seems pretty straight forward when I write it out but I can’t seem to find a way to pull the data needed from the list and apply that to an email already received then forward accordingly...

Comment: So I have decided to change directions in order to get this done but still need some additional help.

Answer (score 0):

The "Alert me" functionality has been in SharePoint for several versions, at least since WSS, i.e. 2003. This legacy functionality does not have an action in modern PowerAutomate.

You say you know how to send the email. That's the action you need. Just put all the field titles and their values into the email body.

**Edit:** to send to the assigned contact, just use that field in the To field of the email.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can get the fields to populate but I was hoping there was a way to send something like the second screen shot / alert me feature. I would like the email to identify what changes were made.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not a feature.

Comment: Is there a way to send an alert to whoever the assigned contact is?

Comment: If you put the assigned contact's email address into the To field, yes.

Comment: But no way to show changes?

Comment: read my comment above.

Comment: When a item is created or modified I receive an alert in my inbox. 

What I want to happen now is that alert be forwarded to the “assigned to” email address from the item. Like this...

Email received as SP alert > data pulled from the list / item (I imagine this will be done external of the actual email but via the list / item itself) > email forwarded to the “assigned to” email address

Seems pretty straight forward when I write it out but I can’t seem to find a way to pull the data needed from the list and apply that to an email already received then forward accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

Second answer for the changed scenario:

to do this with a Flow, you can set up a rule to put the messages into a specific folder. Then use the email trigger "When an email arrives" and point it to that folder.

You cannot use the "Get Item" property to get the item, because the email alert does not give you the item ID, just the title. Since the title may not be unique, that might be a problem.

So, if (and only if) the email contains a field that is a unique identifier for the item, you can parse the email body text to extract the unique value. Then you can use the "Get items" (plural) action and use a oData filter in the Advanced settings to return only the desired item. From there, you can get its ID, then load the item with "Get Item" (singular) and you have all the item properties.

From the properties, get the person to send the email to and copy the trigger email body into the notification.

I have not tested this, but this is the logic of the flow. If the email does not contain anything that uniquely identifies the item, this approach will not work.

Comment: The email would be like the screen shot above. I am thinking the "Project Reference" field would be unique on 99% of the items logged. But since I want the email to forward to the "assigned to" email address I could use that field, no?  Would I use Filter Query or Order By ODATA? Either way the only option is to pull from the email received so how would I pull a specific line of text out of the email body?

Comment: That is exactly the difficulty: you need to parse the email body somehow. Maybe use the field title that you can see in the email, then grab the following characters. Only you can see what that processing logic needs to be. Then use an oData filter to return only one item. If the filter returns more than one item, the whole process does not work. That is the whole point. Identify a single item, get that item, get the "assigned to" and then send the email body on to that person. You will need to be inventive and think outside the box.

Comment: Maybe the words you need to uniquely identify the list item and filter the list are always in the same row of the email body. Then you could split the email body by line break characters. As I said, you need to be inventive, because there is no simple solution for this.